# URL rewriting is not working in HTTPS

Tags: iis, https

URL rewriting has been done in my application which will act both as http and https according to the value passed to the page.
The extension that needs to be mapped has added to the IIS application mapping which was working fine in development environment.
But in testing site the http site is working fine where as https is not.

for ex: http://test1.com is working where as https://test1.com is not working

Can anyone tell me where i made mistake??

Comment: It was a configuration issue. after configure a new site that issue never appears.Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

When a Java application connects to an SSL host it MUST be able to validate its signer.
but for doing self certificate it may face problem for you.
In case for validation use the SSLPoke class as i suggest. And if you cannot  making a simple SSL socket connection for your server in a few lines of java then i will suggest you to use Paid-for certificate . Who's CA chain is *probably* validatable via the existing JRE certificate cacerts file.